# Apache server as reverse proxy is removing xmlns info from html tag

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have a Java application running in tomcat, in front of which I have an Apache http server as a reverse proxy.

However, the proxy is removing all xmlns data from the html tag, which breaks all the Facebook's FBML which is never parsed.

My current config is as follows:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyHTMLDocType XHTML

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /cas /

<Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/cas
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/cas
</Location>

ProxyHTMLURLMap /cas /
SetOutputFilter proxy-html

<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Satisfy all
</Proxy>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use below line in configuration file.

```
<Location> 
xml2StartParse      element     HTML
</Location>
```

This will stops the modification done in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, the `SetOutputFilter proxy-html` has been superseded by `ProxyHTMLEnable On`

Comment: That's on mod-proxy 3.1, we are using 3.0